# Calculate Hits At metric in Theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, theano

I am using `keras` to build a recommender model.  Because the item set is quite large, I'd like to calculate the `Hits @ N metric` as a measure of accuracy.  That is, if the observed item is in the top N predicted, it counts as relevant recommendation.

I was able to build the hits at N function using `numpy`.  But as I'm trying to port it into a custom loss function for `keras`, I'm having problem with the tensors.  Specifically, enumerating over a tensor is different.  And when I looked into the syntax to find something equivalent, I started to question the whole approach.  It's sloppy and slow, reflective of my general python familiarity.

```
def hits_at(y_true, y_pred): #numpy version
    a=y_pred.argsort(axis=1) #ascending, sort by row, return index
    a = np.fliplr(a) #reverse to get descending
    a = a[:,0:10] #return only the first 10 columns of each row
    Ybool = [] #initialze 2D arrray
    for t, idx in enumerate(a):
        ybool = np.zeros(num_items +1) #zero fill; 0 index is reserved
        ybool[idx] = 1 #flip the recommended item from 0 to 1
        Ybool.append(ybool)
    A = map(lambda t: list(t), Ybool)
    right_sum = (A * y_true).max(axis=1) #element-wise multiplication, then find the max
    right_sum = right_sum.sum() #how many times did we score a hit?
    return right_sum/len(y_true) #fraction of observations where we scored a hit
```

How should I approach this in a more compact, and tensor-friendly way?

**Update:**

I was able to get a version of Top 1 working.  I based it loosely on the [GRU4Rec](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06939v4.pdf) description

```
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_idx_sort = T.argsort(-y_pred, axis=1)[:,0] #returns the first element, which is the index of the row with the largest value
    y_act_idx = T.argmax(y_true, axis=1)#returns an array of indexes with the top value
    return T.cast(-T.mean(T.nnet.sigmoid((T.eq(y_pred_idx_sort,y_act_idx)))), theano.config.floatX)`
```

I just had to compare the array of top 1 predictions to the array of the actuals element-wise.  And Theano has an `eq()` function to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independent of N, the number of possible values of your loss function is finite. Therefore it can't be differentiable in a sensible tensor way and you cannot use it as loss function in Keras / Theano. You may try to use a theano log loss with top N guys.

UPDATE :

In Keras - you may write your own loss functions. They have a declaration of a form :

```
def loss_function(y_pred, y_true):
```

Both `y_true` and `y_pred` are numpy arrays, so you may obtain easly a vector `v` which is 1 when an example given is in top 500 and 0 otherwise. Then you may transform it to theano tensor constant vector and apply it in a way :

```
return theano.tensor.net.binary_crossentropy(y_pred * v, y_true * v)
```

This should work correctly.

UPDATE 2:

Log loss is the same thing what binary_crossentropy.

Comment: I'm currently using categorical_crossentropy; I'm not familiar with "log loss with top N".  Is it a matter of extending http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html#the-model in some way?

Comment: Hrm, it seems that y_pred and y_true are actually tensors, and not numpy arrays.  that complicates it a bit because finding domensions and iterating over them are more complicated than doing the same for a numpy array.

Comment: This is beyond my ability to code.  However the logic soundly answers the question, so I'm happy to accept it as correct.

Comment: I had similiar issue during working on one of my work projects. It worked - but it was with older version of Keras. I will also use similliar thing in closest future so I will share results of my research then :) Thanks :)

Comment: That would be very helpful of you if you happen to think of it; thank you!